# VBA to Change Worksheet Tab Color Based on Referenced Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, colors, tabs

I have a Workbook used by up to 12 personnel that can contain various Worksheets of varying names depending on the tasks.  Each Worksheet gets assigned to one of the 12 personnel and assignments can change.

For ease of assignment reviews, I'd like for the Worksheet Tab to change color to the assigned personnel.

The names of the personnel and their assigned color are located on the Worksheet named SETUP and located in Cells between E97 and H99.  E100 is left blank to check if no one is assigned and to leave the sheet tab with no color.

On each Worksheet, the person assigned to it is located in Cell Q1.

This macro works except if one of the 12 cells is left blank.  It then colors the tab with the associated color.  If the assignment field is left blank or does not match, how do I get it to skip the worksheet and move onto the next?

```
Sub TabColorAssign()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        TabColor WS
    Next WS
End Sub

Private Sub TabColor(WS As Worksheet)

  If WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("E97") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(184, 204, 228)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("F97") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(196, 215, 155)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("G97") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(250, 191, 143)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("H97") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(177, 160, 199)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("E98") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("F98") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(218, 150, 148)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("G98") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(206, 255, 95)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("H98") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(139, 202, 217)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("E99") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(137, 255, 204)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("F99") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 185, 255)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("G99") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("H99") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = RGB(196, 189, 151)
  ElseIf WS.Range("Q1").Value = Worksheets("Setup").Range("E100") Then
    WS.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone
  End If
End Sub
```

The last ElseIf statement is what I've tried but the Worksheet Tab still receives the color of the blank assignment cell.  There's no error so I'm not sure what I have wrong.

Comment: When you execute the TabColorAssign() ? In whitch event ?

Comment: Else WS.Tab.Color = xlColorIndexNone End If  .... if not match in previus comparisons, ONLY else

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`WS.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

The `Color` property expects an RGB value, but you're passing  `xlColorIndexNone` so you need to use the `ColorIndex` property.

FYI if you set the fill color for each name cell on the "setup" sheet you can do something like this (which may be easier to maintain)

```vb
Sub TabColorAssign()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        TabColor WS
    Next WS
End Sub

Private Sub TabColor(WS As Worksheet)
    Dim v, f As Range
    
    v = WS.Range("Q1").Value
    
    If Len(v) > 0 Then Set f = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Setup"). _
                  Range("E97:H99").Find(what:=v, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        WS.Tab.Color = f.Interior.Color
    Else
        WS.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End If
    
End Sub
```